# Importerror with Python Buffer Library

Tags: python, buffer, importerror

I downloaded this library: https://github.com/bufferapp/buffer-python

Ran the setup.py install, and then tried to run some code using the newly installed library.

What happens though is I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twitter-quote-bot.py", line 14, in <module>
    from buffpy.managers.profiles import Profiles
ImportError: No module named managers.profiles
```

The only way I've found to fix it is to move my program (twitter-quote-bot) into the downloaded folder from Buffer and run it there.

Did I do something wrong in the installation? It seems like I should be able to do these imports globally.

Thanks in advance!